# How to cast an object to color iff possible

Tags: c#

I'm getting an object passed as a parameter and i want to cast it to `Color` if it is possible. Sometimes tho this `object` (`value`) cant be casted to `Color`... since i cannot just use:

```
Color color = value as Color;
```

and this line of code will throw an exception if the object cant be casted:

```
Color color = (Color)value;
```

and i dont want to use try..catch for this. I cannot think of a way to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator:

```
if (value is Color)
{
    Color color = (Color)value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "is" keyword:

```
if(value is Color)
{
  //cast to Color
}
```

[link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/scekt9xw.aspx)